# Expressão regex para encontrar mais de uma ocorrencia na mesma string

Tags: php, regex, template

Estou desenvolvendo um template engine em PHP para questões de aprendizado pois sou novo em programação, e gostaria de um forma de encontrar mais de um #include() em minha view, pois a que eu tenho atualmente não encontra todos os includes somente o primeiro.

Comment: Coloque o código que você esta usando para exemplificar o seu problema. Desta maneira como está ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar.
Aproveite e faça um [tour] pela plataforma para aprender mais ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] gostaria de um forma de encontrar mais de um #include() em minha view, pois a que eu tenho atualmente não encontra todos os includes somente o primeiro.

Sugiro que use **flag global** na sua regex, pois segundo você ela já encontra o primeiro include e não continua dando match.

Segue um exemplo [sem a **flag global**](https://regex101.com/r/qkd3mU/5) e um exemplo [com a **flag global**](https://regex101.com/r/qkd3mU/4)

Exemplo de uso no seu programa php:

```
<?php
$subject = "string do seu arquivo que vai ser analisado aqui";
$pattern = '/(include .*)/'; //insira seu padrão regex aqui
preg_match_all($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Note que ao invés do uso de `preg_match` é usado `preg_match_all`, isso faz com que todas as ocorrências de match do pattern sejam retornadas

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @NeversonSilva uhu! só marcar como correta agora. Isso ajuda as outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida que entrarem nessa página a achar a resposta correta